# getting last logins since $time

Tags: last

I want to get last logins from a certain date using `last`

Running

```
last -f /var/log/btmp -t 20140723123000
```

Always shows my whole lastb log.

This:

```
last -t 20140723123000
```

Shows my whole last log. eg:

```
bob     pts/1        172.16.14.37     Thu Feb 27 09:38 - 09:56 (4+00:18)
tim     pts/1        172.16.14.37     Wed Feb 19 11:32 - 09:34 (7+22:02)
root     pts/1        172.16.14.37     Mon Feb 17 09:50 - 12:04 (1+02:14)
```

The [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last) seems to say "Display the state of logins as of the specified time"

There is no year outputted, is this an issue?

Update:

Red Hat 5.5

Running last -V
returns : last: invalid option -- V
(running man last shows no -V option)

Running last -s
returns : last: invalid option -- s
(running man last shows no -s option)

Comment: you can use `-F` as the manual suggests to get full information.

Comment: man last doesn't show -F as an option, and I get invalid option -- F when trying to use it. I don't think thats the reason -t isn't working though.

Comment: Can you update the question and show  `last -V`  Also, have you looked at the `-s` flag?  What system are you running?

Comment: What is your actual question here? Are you asking if vthe lack of year is a bug? There's no year because it is _this_ year.

Comment: The question is , why when I run `last -t 20140723123000` do I get logins from January, March etc.

Comment: @Kiksy the `-t, --until  time`  option is  untill the specified time not `-s, --since time`  which is what you want imo.  Can you pastebin  `man last`  somewhere?

Comment: Man last pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DVFEfugL

Comment: Well I have no idea what `last` that is. It seems to be a fork or something.  I've looked at mine and also here http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/last.1.html   Both discuss the `-s` flag.